# hadoop get files from existing archived file in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, archive

I have a directory "SmallFiles" that contains 8 files, I archived them using "hadoop archive -archiveName myArch.har -p /Files/SmallFiles /Files" then deleted the original files.
I want to know how to extract files again?

When I download it I get these 3 files "index, masterindex, part-0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access archived files via the har:// URI.

Thus, files archived with:
`hadoop archive -archiveName foo.har -p /user/hadoop dir1 dir2 /user/zoo`
would be accessed with
`hadoop dfs -lsr har:///user/zoo/foo.har/`

I think the docs are straightforward here:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-archives/HadoopArchives.html

Comment: It worked, but why my files are taking 512MB for each block? Original files took 128MB each

Comment: I haven't been able to confirm this, but I would assume the default block size for har files may be larger, since that's kind of what you're trying to do - combine a large number of small files into a smaller number of larger files.   Keep in mind that the purpose of HAR is to reduce load on the NameNode by reducing the total number of files to keep track of.   It's purpose is *not* to compress data, it's to reduce the number of files the NameNode has to manage.